# Data encryption on phonegap

Tags: encryption, cordova

In my application I want to use data encryption on phonegap. How can I achieve this? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, what do you want to encrypt and why?

Comment: @Kris Erickson i have some data in database...If i want to use data that time i will decide to use decryption....